# Rotate CAShapeLayer around it center without moving postion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to rotate a CAShapeLayer with objective c around it center point without moving it  around. The CAShapeLayer contain UIBezierPath point of rect.  I'm not able to rotate the CAShapeLayer becouse i dont know how. Please show me how tp rotate around it center without moving it postion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - Rotate a layer right and left using two different UIButtons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170772/ios-rotate-a-layer-right-and-left-using-two-different-uibuttons)

Comment: I see your problem. Could you tell us more about the kind of shape you draw as BezierPath ?

Comment: I'm drawing as bezierPathWithRect

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does that:

```
//Create a CABasicAnimation object to manage our rotation.
CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
totalAnimationTime = rotation_count;

rotation.duration =  totalAnimationTime;

//Start the animation at the previous value of angle
rotation.fromValue = @(angle);

//Add change (which will be a change of +/- 2pi*rotation_count
angle += change;

//Set the ending value of the rotation to the new angle.
rotation.toValue = @(angle);

//Have the rotation use linear timing.
rotation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

/*
 This is the magic bit. We add a CAValueFunction that tells the CAAnimation we are modifying
 the transform's rotation around the Z axis.
 Without this, we would supply a transform as the fromValue and toValue, and for rotations
  > a half-turn, we could not control the rotation direction.

 By using a value function, we can specify arbitrary rotation amounts and directions, and even
 Rotations greater than 360 degrees.
*/

rotation.valueFunction = [CAValueFunction functionWithName: kCAValueFunctionRotateZ];


/*
  Set the layer's transform to it's final state before submitting the animation, so it is in it's
  final state once the animation completes.
 */
imageViewToAnimate.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(imageViewToAnimate.layer.transform, angle, 0, 0, 1.0);

//Now actually add the animation to the layer.
[imageViewToAnimate.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

(That code is taken (and simplified) from my github project [**KeyframeViewAnimations**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations))

In my project I'm rotating the layer of a `UIImageView`, but the same approach will work for any `CALayer` type.

Comment: that dont rotate around the objects center, the object move postion